# How play .mp3 files loaded from a URL in TMediaPlayer with Firemonkey?

Tags: mp3, media-player, firemonkey, playback, delphi-xe7

Is there any way to play .mp3 files from a URL using TMediaPlayer with Firemonkey in Delphi XE7?, this code doesn't works;

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'http://wwww.some_site.com/some_song.mp3';
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

it throws an exception of File not found, so I suppose that TMediaPlayer works  only with local files, isn't it?, please, any helps it would be very appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the [`TMediaPlayer.FileName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer.FileName) property, it simply extracts the file extension from the end of the specified path (everything after, and including, the final `.` character), locates a registered codec for that extension, and then tells the codec to load the `FileName` value as-is.  The codec returns a [`TMedia`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMedia) object which [`TMediaPlayer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer) then uses to play/control the media as needed.  By default, FireMonkey only implements [`TMedia`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMedia) classes for local files.

You would have to implement a custom [`TMedia`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMedia)-derived class to handle streaming media, and a custom [`TCustomMediaCodec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TCustomMediaCodec)-derived class (registered for a custom file extension using [`TMediaCodecManager.RegisterMediaCodecClass()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaCodecManager.RegisterMediaCodecClass)) to create your [`TMedia`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMedia) class. Then you can assign a URL to [`TMediaPlayer.FileName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer.FileName) that ends with your extension (the real URL would not, so your codec would have to strip it off before accessing the URL), eg:

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'http://wwww.some_site.com/some_song.mp3.myext';
```

Comment: Thanks very much Remy, your answer made me understand how TMedia works and will test with your feedback.

Comment: It Delphi 11.0 "Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Media\StreamingMedia" it is shown that TMediaPlayer supports URLs in the Filename property (at least on Windows, not sure if that works cross-platform)