# java.io.ioexception: Prepare failed status while playing Audio streaming in Android using Delphi 10.4.1

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Delphi **10.4.1** for developing android mobile application. I'm trying to use the media file name from the cloud file (http://publicipaddress:8000/playfile.mp3). And this files is playing properly in web browser. And When I tried the following code, I have received the excetion **java.io.ioexception: Prepare failed status**.

```
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'http://publicipaddress:8000/playfile.mp3';
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

Please help to resolve this issue. And I found few solution related to [JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479574/android-mediaplayer-java-io-ioexception-prepare-failed-status-0x1) but don't know how to implement in Delphi. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work with `https` URLs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How play .mp3 files loaded from a URL in TMediaPlayer with Firemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974230/how-play-mp3-files-loaded-from-a-url-in-tmediaplayer-with-firemonkey)

Comment: I'm facing this excetion java.io.ioexception: Prepare failed status.

Comment: The standard `TMediaPlayer` class does not support streaming. In the first step, you need to download the stream to a temporary file by using THTTPClient. Secondly, you can reference in `TMediaPlayer.filename` to that temporary downloaded file.